# Regex exact match

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex to match this pattern exactly:

```
20819521|1
```

A sequence of numbers at the beginning

A separator |

A single number between 0-9

This is what I have so far

It doesn't give me an exact match

```
/\d*\|[1-9]/g
```

Comment: Try `[0-9]+\|[0-9]` or use anchors `^[0-9]+\|[0-9]$` or word boundaries `\b` https://regex101.com/r/INvM5J/1

Comment: What do you mean by "exact match"? `*` is "between 0 and unlimited times"

Comment: @Thefourthbird This wouldn't work with this input, notice the input has the letter d, still gives me a match, I want this to match to numbers only at the beginning not a portion of numbers: 208195214564975615d654|1

Comment: @EricBergman Try the version with the anchors https://regex101.com/r/o4Gz79/1

Comment: I'm still not sure what the problem is. How exactly does `\d+\|\d` not work (note the `+` instead of `*`)?

Comment: @Thefourthbird the last one worked, please post it as an answer so I can accept it, thanks

Comment: @EricBergman You are welcome. You could accept the posted answer as it also matched your desired result.

Comment: this would be a bit shorter solution, though: `^\d+\|\d$`; still to get the question reopen (to make it more useful for others and potentially for getting more upvotes/retracting downvotes) you should describe what are the cases you tested your attempt-solution on, what were the expected and the actual results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want an exact match of 8 digits, a pipe (`|`) and another digit. That would mean you want something like the following:

```
/^\d{8}\|\d$/
```

```js
console.log(/^\d{8}\|\d$/.test('20819521|1')) // Match
console.log(/^\d{8}\|\d$/.test('2081952|1')) // No Match
console.log(/^\d{8}\|\d$/.test('2081952a|1')) // Also no Match
console.log(/^\d{8}\|\d$/.test('2081952a|11')) // Also no Match
```